# Rails 4 – How to rescue from NoMethodError and continue trying method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rescue

In my Contacts class, after a contact is created with their email address, I try to pull as much contact data from FullContact's API as possible.

I'm having this issue where if one column of data doesn't exist for a "person" in FullContact, it throws a NoMethodError and I don't get to save the rest of the data that potentially does exist to the contact, because my method stops at the error.

How can I rescue from a NoMethodError and get my method to continue running the rest of it? Like for it to just skip over the error and try the rest of the code. I've tried `next` and `continue` in my rescue code but that doesn't work.

Thanks for any help.

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user

  after_create do |contact|
    contact.delay.update_fullcontact_data
  end

  def update_fullcontact_data

    person = FullContact.person(self.email) 

    if person.contact_info.given_name.present? 
      self.name = person.contact_info.given_name 
    end

    if person.contact_info.family_name.present? 
      self.last_name = person.contact_info.family_name
    end

    if person.demographics.location_general.present?
      self.city = person.demographics.location_general
    end

    save!

  rescue NoMethodError => exception
   puts "Hit a NoMethodError"
   save!
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea to rescue NoMethodError like this ... you may end up with troubles running into unexpected behaviors such as you making a typo and it still rescues it and save, and you have no idea where it comes from

Comment: Good point. However I'm currently still rescuing from NoMethodError because I figured it's best that any data pulled from FullContact gets saved, considering we pay per successful api call. Open to alternatives.

Comment: you can also use .respond_to? to check if a method is present other than trying to hit it regardless and rescue from the exception (for non-rails apps)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in general what may be a solution for your problem is `try` method (http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try). To make the story short - it returns nil instead of raising exception if method does not exist on specific object

Comment: Hmm @djaszczurowski how would you do this with the code I'm giving?

Comment: `if person.try(:contact_info).try(:family_name).present? 
      self.last_name = person.contact_info.family_name
end`

if contact_info method is guaranteed then I would call `if person.contact_info.try(:family_name).present?`

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to make sure it saves, you can use `ensure` do something like this:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :user

  after_create do |contact|
    contact.delay.update_fullcontact_data
  end

  def update_fullcontact_data

    person = FullContact.person(self.email) 

    if person.contact_info.given_name.present? 
      self.name = person.contact_info.given_name 
    end

    if person.contact_info.family_name.present? 
      self.last_name = person.contact_info.family_name
    end

    if person.demographics.location_general.present?
      self.city = person.demographics.location_general
    end

    save!

  ensure
   save!
  end
end
```

More info:
http://blog.rubybestpractices.com/posts/rklemme/003-The_Universe_between_begin_and_end.html